# How to print NSData with UTF-8 string

Tags: objective-c, encoding, printing, utf-8

I have a Star Micronics SM-S220i bluetooth printer. I'm using it to print receipts from my iPad application. I can't get UTF-8 chars like åäö to work though.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableData *commands = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[commands appendData:[@"\nåäö\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]];
```

When using this encoding it prints åäö in DOS chars.

Comment: I know it's an obvious question but have you tried using NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of the Windows one?

Comment: Yeah, already tried that. It's converting åäö to ├Ñ├ñ├║

Comment: What do you mean by "it prints åäö in DOS chars" ? Does it print "å" or some other character? Do you have technical documentation of the printer about the code page used?

Comment: With the encoding used in my question (NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding) it prints å as σ that is a DOS character. And yes, they have technical documentation and even a SDK but it's in english so they don't use UTF-8 chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If "å" converted to CP1292 is printed as "σ" then the printer probably expects the data in CP437 encoding. CP437 is available as `kCFStringEncodingDOSLatinUS` which can be converted to a NSString encoding:

```
NSMutableData *commands = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSStringEncoding cp437 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingDOSLatinUS);
[commands appendData:[@"\nåäö\n" dataUsingEncoding:cp437]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different encoding, e.g.:

```
[commands appendData:[@"\nåäö\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Tried, just converts åäö to ├Ñ├ñ├║

Comment: By "e.g." I was suggesting you try ALL the available (or, at least, plausible) encodings. Such as `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`, for a start. It really does look like an encoding/decoding mis-match.